# AngularJS multi dimension array calling ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs, html-lists

I am trying to get the inner array of the array main in side_menu_angular.js. The first part of the array, i am able to detect it and it works. From the second on wards did not work. My structure of my HTML is slightly different which I think it affects the calling of those inner arrays. What have I done wrong here or have I missed out?
Below are my codes:

HTML

```
<div ng-app="theme" ng-controller="sideController">
    <div id="mainSlideout"> 
        <div id="mainSlideMenu">
            <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                <li class="active" ng-repeat="main in menuName">
                    <h3><a class="mainMenuItem" id="photography">{{main.main_menu}}</a></h3>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="slideout"> 
        <div id="slideMenu" >
            <ul style="list-style-type: none;" >
                <li class="active" ng-repeat-start="sub in menuName" ng-repeat="menus in sub.main_content">
                    <h3><a class="menuItem" id="{{menus.name}}">{{menus.name}}</a></h3>
                </li>
                <li id="{{subMenu.id}}" class="draggable {{menus.name}}" ng-repeat="subMenu in menus.element" ng-repeat-end>
                    <img ng-src="{{subMenu.template}}" id="{{subMenu.id}}" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

side_menu_angular.js

```
    angular.module( 'theme' , [
    ] ).controller('sideController' , function($scope){
        $scope.menuName = [ 
        { main_menu:'Photography' , main_content:[
            { name:'Header' , element:[ 
                { id:'template1' , template:'wp-content/themes/dynamictheme/img/template/header/template1.png' }, 
                { id:'template2' , template:'wp-content/themes/dynamictheme/img/template/header/template2.png' }
                ]
            },
            { name:'Content' , element:[ 
                { id:'template3' , template:'wp-content/themes/dynamictheme/img/template/header/template3.png' }
                ]
            },
            { name:'Footer' , element:[ 
                { id:'template4' , template:'wp-content/themes/dynamictheme/img/template/header/template4.png' }
                ]
            }]
        }];
    })
;
```

Comment: I tried to plunk it, and you have to do some nested ng-repeat to make this work. But I find it easier to write a directive. please upload a plunk with the necessary code and it would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here.

```
<li id="{{subMenu.id}}" class="draggable {{menus.name}}" ng-repeat="subMenu in menus.element" ng-repeat-end>
    <img ng-src="{{subMenu.template}}" id="{{subMenu.id}}" />
</li>
```

You have used `subMenu in menus.element` but `menus` is not available to this ng-repeat. Only `sub` is available here as it lies within the `ng-repeat-start` block.

[Here](http://vanderwijk.info/blog/nesting-ng-repeat-start/) is a good solution which explains about nesting `ng-repeat-start`s which seems like a nice solution.

Comment: I think I have fixed that problem. by putting the ng-repeat"sub in menuName" to it's above tag. <ul style="list-style-type: none;" id="{{sub.main_menu}}" ng-repeat="sub in menuName"> . The scope wasn't being able to detect below. As of your answer, i leave it as it was, and it is working. Anyway, thank you for the help for allowing me to gain additional knowledge of nested ng-repeat.

Comment: You mean to say you found out answer on your own? Because I don't see any ng-repeat applied to `ul` in the question. Anyway, glad everything worked in the end!